# JS Socket | Add full array on the site

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

So I have a kinda bug on my socket system. I have a array which will be emited if new connection is made to the site, but the problem is that it will be called on all users. So if I have there `console.log('new user')` then everyone will receive it to the console. My question is, how can I do it so the only one user who just connected receives only it?

Here is my server

```
io.on('connection', function(client){
    clients.push(client.id);
        io.emit('add games', coinflips); //This is the line
    console.log(clients);
    client.on('disconnect', function(){
        clients.splice(client.indexOf, 1);
        console.log(clients);
    });
});
```

Here is how it's being handled

```
socket.on('add games', function(data){
    if(data.length > 0){
        addGames(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the the socket id, `socket.id` then send to that id.
something along this line.

```
io.of('/mynamespace').sockets[socketID].emit(...)
```

Event this logic could work

```
clients = [];
```

then whenever a connection is made.

```
 clients.push(socket);
```

then in the clients array, just index it.

```
clients[0].emit(...)
```

this is how you get a id upon connection.

```
console.info('Client id (id=' + socket.id + ').');
```

Socket.IO allows you to “namespace” your sockets, which essentially means assigning different endpoints or paths.

Namespaces are useful features to minimize the number of resources (TCP connections) and at the same time separate concerns within your application by introducing separation between communication channels. Multiple namespaces actually share the same WebSockets connection thus saving us socket ports on the server.

Namespaces are created on the server side. But they are joined by clients by sending a request to the server.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Default Namespaces
The root namespace '/' is the default namespace which is joined by clients if a namespace is not specified by the client while connecting to the server. All connections to the server using the socket object client side are made to the default namespace.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Custom Namespaces
We can create our own custom namespaces. To set up a custom namespace, we can call the of function on the server-side:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendfile('index.html');
});

var nsp = io.of('/my-namespace');
nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('someone connected');
nsp.emit('hi', 'Hello everyone!');
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but what does the /mynamespace point at?

Comment: if you read the docs, it is custom namespace can you create to listen and emit events accordingly.

Comment: that is custom namespace you can use the default if you so desire.

Comment: check update answer for a more direct explanation to your question about namespaces.